# RegExp: Possible to use a negative lookahead before a match term?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been asked to create a find-and-replace tool in JavaScript. (Note: This question is *not* limited to JavaScript, but is applicable to all languages that support the `(?!dont match this)` Regular Expression syntax. )

Basically, someone is able to enter a list of words and a list of replacements.
Finally, the user is able to enter a list of word-combinations that should be excluded.

An example:

input string:

```
blue moutain
blue sea
blue grass
foo
foo foo
```

list of find/replace terms *( shown here next to each other for clarity)*

```
blue -> red
sea -> ocean
foo -> bar
```

list of exceptions:

```
blue mountain
blue sea
foo foo
```

My system is able to use these lists to construct regular expressions of the kind:

```
/\s*(blue)(?!\s*(mountain|sea)\s*))/
```

which works great. The problem is that I can only get the negative lookahead working *after* the word. (Of course, the name 'negative **lookahead**' might indeed be chosen with a reason.)

The problem is for instance with `foo foo`. The tool sees the first `foo` and realizes that it is followed by another, which the regexp `/\s*(foo)(?!\s*(foo)\s*))/` does not allow. However, then it goes on to the second `foo`, which is not followed by anything. Therefore, it is replaced, changing the `foo foo` line to `foo bar`.

So... to sum things up:

Why does [this regexp](http://rubular.com/r/mJguwi9da1) (`(?!foo)\s*foo`) match the second foo?

Comment: The `(?!foo)\s*foo` regex matches the second `foo` Iin `foo foo` because it is not a lookbehind. No idea what a solution could be for JS.

Answer (score 1):

Cause if you type only `(?!foo)` it will take all positions not followed by `foo`:

[live here.](https://regex101.com/r/yJ9tL7/1)

Then in those positions it will look for `\s*foo`:

[live here.](https://regex101.com/r/yJ9tL7/2)

Comment: Ah! So `(?!foo)` means *match every position not immediately followed by foo*?

Comment: @Qqwy. Exactly, you got it !